# Animate Spin SVG Element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-animate

I want to animate the transformation of this SVG element. I wish this worked:

```
$(this).find('polygon').animate({
    transform: "rotate(360)"
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @BarryDoyle no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f921oh4w/) i made for you. You could add an extra class and put the animation on that extra class.

```
.chevron.rotate {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

and then do this in your javascript:

```
$('.rotate-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.chevron').addClass('rotate');
});
```

Comment: I had to add "transformation-origin" to get the spin effect I was looking for but this worked. Thanks.